# ¿Cómo calcular horas habiles entre dos en php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero encontrar cuantas horas hábiles han pasado, teniendo en cuenta como día hábil de lunes a viernes de 8am a 5pm.
Ejemplo si yo cree un registro el 2021-12-06 18:21:02, que me indique cuantas horas habiles han pasado.

Answer (score 1):

con carbón lo puede hacer de una forma mas simple, aquí esta la librería
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

si lo desea calcular la diferencia de horas en JavaScript puede utilizar  momentjs

https://momentjs.com/

```
use Carbon\Carbon;



 $inicio = Carbon::parse('2021-12-06 14:21:02');
 $final = Carbon::parse('2021-12-06 18:31:02');

 $intervaloM= $inicio->diffInMinutes($final);

 $intervaloH= $inicio->diffInHours($final);
 echo  $intervaloM;
 echo  $intervaloH;exit();
```